# Can two computers on different wifi networks have same local IP address? (ex. 192.168.0.1 for both systems on diff. network)

Tags: node.js, express, networking

I have a validation in NodeJS where I need a IP of system to validate duplicate requests. Here, I'm confused about the uniqueness of the local IP addresses for the systems on different WIFI networks. Can they be same for both systems or are always unique?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two computers can have same IP on two contiguous networks in RFC 1918 address space, that is private range. Considering those two networks talk to each other using NAT, Network Address Translation.

Two computers cannot have same address when they are using IPs from public address space if they are connected to the Internet.